# How to fix error "cannot import name 'ModelMetaclass' from 'pydantic.main'"

Tags: python, import, importerror, pydantic, pytorch-lightning

I'm trying to import the lightning package for a python program and I keep getting this error message: cannot import name 'ModelMetaclass' from 'pydantic.main' (c:\Users\mt767\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pydantic\main.py).

I have checked that the pydantic package is up to date, and I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling it. None of the solutions I've found online have worked. The code is simply importing the lightning package:

`import lightning`

Comment: https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/issues/18027

Answer (score 8):

Uninstall the latest version i.e. 2.0.4 and install the 2.0.1

pip install lightning==2.0.1

It had resolved the problem for me to the point i uninstall the 2.0.1 version and install 2.0.4 version and it work with it as well